# How can I paste an image into MS word copied from CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have been working with **CKEditor** and able to implement my own version that can save existing files in the **CKEditor** to database.
 [image]

Here, I can upload any image from my pc or by url link into the CKEditor. But when I copy the image and paste it to MS word it's not working. I have searched and found some plugins that might work but every plugins work for pasting an image from MS word file to CKEditor. Rather, I want the reverse, copy the image file from CKEditor and past it to the word.

Could some one suggest me any plugin or solution regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload image in this pattern :

http://10.11.201.84/document-editor/uploaded/applet1.PNG

Use http in your url . Then Your image can be pasted from ckeditor to word .

Comment: Awesome. It works. Many thanks. Btw..  @Sagor Ahmed .. can you briefly explain why http:// is compulsory in this case and the architecture inside it ?